# Unable to install pywinauto tool

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

Unable to install pywinauto with below error. Please help me to over come this.

```
C:\Python27>python C:\Users\........\Downloads\pywinauto-0.4.0\pywinauto-0.4.
0\setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'pywinauto' does not exist
```

Comment: Thanks cgohlke, I able to cross this error but failed at another point the cause is '*running install_egg_info
Writing C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
The following module has to be installed before running pywinauto...
        SendKeys*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1. Downloaded http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/ (32 bit)
2. Installed python using python-2.6.6.msi
3. Install send keys
   https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/downloads/detail?name=SendKeys-0.3_py26.exe&can=2&q=
4. Downloaded
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/files/pywinauto/0.4.0/
5. Unzip the pywinauto zip file to a folder
6. Run python.exe setup.py install

> C:\Software\pywinauto-0.4.0\pywinauto-0.4.0>C:\Python26\python.exe
>   setup.py install

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it was this:

1. Extracted the .zip file
2. Moved the folder into:`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`
3. Ran setup.py by going into the folder and double-clicking it.

That worked for me, and that is the normal way of moving modules into Python.

Answer (score 0):

This issue :`"error: package directory 'pywinauto' does not exist"` appears if you start setup process from wrong work dirrectory.

In my case (Win7x64, ActivePython2.7.2) I got same issue till I done next:
*precondtion: you should install Python first

1) go in PowerShell to directory with unzipped PyWinAuto: `"cd: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto"`
you should navigate to folder with unzipped PyWinAuto

2) then do `"python setup.py install"`

Then you can check for installed PyWinAuto:

```
1) "import application"
2) "app = application.Application().start_("notepad")"
```

notepad.exe should appears